# Пустая строка передается $_POST. Почему?

Tags: php, массивы, post, mysqli

Помогаю знакомым делать студенческий проект. 
Суть такова:

По заполненным полям формы на странице делается выборка в БД и достаются результаты.
Скрипт исполняется тут же на странице. По `submit`'у методом `POST` на странице вызывается функция `fetchFlats()`, возвращающая массив значений из базы.

Возникла проблема - форму не удается проверить на заполненность - текстовые `input` оказываются заполненными пустыми строками при каждом вызове функции. То есть в поля еще ничего не введено, но массив с данными приходит. Дополнительный `Header` проблему не решил.

Подскажите, пожалуйста,  как избавиться от этих пустых строк.
Очень-очень срочно нужно.

**index.php**, где и происходит действие:

```
<?php
//Подключение библиотек
require "inc/db.inc.php";
require "inc/lib.inc.php";

//header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8');
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>База</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
    <fieldset legend="Укажите парпаметры выбора">
        <form action="" method="post">
              <select name="city">
                    <option selected disabled>Выберите город</option>
                    <?$cities = selectCity();
                      foreach ($cities as $city) {?>
                    <option value="<?=$city['ID_City']?>"><?=$city['Name']?>      

   </option>
                    <?}?>
              </select>
              <select name="metro">
                    <option selected disabled>Выберите метро</option>  
                    <?$metros = selectMetro();
                      foreach ($metros as $metro) {?>
                    <option value="<?=$metro['ID_Metro']?>"><?=$metro['Name']?

    ></option>      
                    <?}?>
              </select>
              <label for="area">
                Общая площадь
                <input type="text" name="area"/>
              </label>
              <label for="price">
                Цена
                <input type="text" name="price"/>
              </label>
              <button type="submit">Показать варианты</button>
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <? 
              if(empty($_POST) ){//Блок с вызовом функции
                echo 'Введите данные для поиска!';
              } else {
                $flats = fetchFlats();
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($flats);
                print_r($_POST);
                echo "</pre>";
             }
            ?>  
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Функция `fetchFlats` в подключаемом файле **lib.inc.php**: (чтобы хоть не совсем говнокод был)

```
function fetchFlats() {
    global $link;
    $where = '';
    $and = ' AND ';
    if(isset($_POST['city'])) {
        $where .= 'WHERE rc.id_city = '.$_POST['city'];
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM flat f
            INNER JOIN building b ON f.id_building = b.id_building
            INNER JOIN residential_complex rc ON b.id_residential_complex = rc.id_residential_complex ".$where;

    if (!$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $items = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        return $items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну наверное не при каждом вызове, а при первом открытии страницы. После того как заполнить поля и отправить форму `$_POST` не будет пустым. Это происходит потому, что php формирует страницу сразу и целиком и выдает в браузер. Весь код php уже отработал когда страница в браузере.

Предлагаю: в `form` положить еще одно поле `<input type="hidden" name="subm" values="abc">`

И в том месте где Вы проверяете на заполненность, проверять не на пустой `$_POST`, а на отсутствие в нем нужных Вам данных.

`if(empty($_POST))` ничего не делать (если данных из `hidden` поля не было - значит еще не отправляли форму)

`if(!$_POST['price'] || ! ... )` ошибка - введите данные.

**P.S.** Во 2м кусе кода

```
$where .= 'WHERE rc.id_city = '.$_POST['city'];`
```

так делать нельзя, SQL-инъекция уже напрашивается ...
используйте хотя-бы

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city'])
```

Comment: Там и с mysql_real_escape_string будет SQL-инъекция, раз значение в кавычки не обернуто. Можно intval заюзать, вместо этого всего.

Comment: Вы, кажется, не поняли сути вопроса. У меня при отправке пустой формы все поля по идее должны быть пустыми. Сейчас же при отправке пустой формы в массиве POST присутствуют в четырех параметрах пустые строки. Этого быть не должно. Если поля пустые, то параметры не должны быть isset, от этого зависит правильность построения строки sql-запроса. 
Мне нужно чтобы этих пустых строк не было при отправке пустой формы. Вот.

Comment: Ну это особенность работы браузеров при отправке формы. Как подавить такое их поведение - не знаю. Разве что самому собирать ответ JS на стороне клиента. Так что самое простое, как мне кажется, пробежаться по $_POST и удалить из него пустые элементы. после чего уже проверять его и т.п.

Comment: Я уже применял предварительно unset, но это тоже не помогает - в случае если нам придет нормальное значение вместо пустой строки, теперь просто треяюсь. Никогда с этим не сталкивался прежде

Comment: Не понял фразы ... чем мешает unset нормальным значениям. unset делать только if(empty(...)). и может действительно, как предлагали ниже проверять на empty вместо isset

Comment: Да, unset очень помог, сам догадался, но спасибо всем)

Answer (score 0):

При отправке формы всегда передаются значения из формы, даже пустые строки, но, всё же это строки, и поэтому `isset()` возвращает `true`

Используй функцию `empty()` чтобы проверить что строка не пустая

Comment: Да,  ` empty()`  возвращает `true` в моем случае, но параметр все равно остается isset(), то есть он присутствует в массиве post. Мне же нужно, чтобы этих пустых строк при отправке пустой формы вообще не появлялось и не было, и выводилось сообщение о том, что нужно заполнить хотя бы некоторые данные. Чтобы пустая форма была полностью пустой. 
От того, присутствуют ли в массиве post пустые строки, в моем случае зависит правильность составления строки sql-запроса в функции(там несколько критериев). 
И это превращается в большую проблему уже.

Comment: на будущее - форма всегда всегда передаёт все поля, а пустая форма - форма с пустыми полями